# Observation in a bivariate Ellipse

Tags: r

[image]I am trying find the probability that a point lies within an ellipse?
For eg if I was plotting the bivariate data (x,y) for 300 datasets in an 95% ellipsoid region, how do I calculate how many times out of 300 will my points fall inside the
ellipse?

Heres the code I am using

```
   library(MASS)
   seed<-1234
   x<-NULL
   k<-1
   Sigma2 <- matrix(c(.72,.57,.57,.46),2,2)
   Sigma2
   rho <- Sigma2[1,2]/sqrt(Sigma2[1,1]*Sigma2[2,2])
   rho
   eta1<-replicate(300,mvrnorm(k, mu=c(-1.59,-2.44), Sigma2))

   library(car)
   dataEllipse(eta1[1,],eta1[2,], levels=c(0.05, 0.95))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Um, if it is a 95% ellipse, then the probability IS 95%, by definition. 95% of 300 is 285. WTP?

Comment: Yes. That was my impression when I saw it on Rhelp earlier today. To user1560215 aka Anamika Chaudhuri, you are asked not to crosspost to Rhelp.

Comment: DWin, I understand I am not allowed to crosspost if I had received responses from the other post but I didnt.

Comment: Woodchips, that was my understanding too but the figure above which was created using the above code doesnot show that there are 5 points outside of the ellipse. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You are missing an understanding of statistics, and how noisy data works. This question is clearly posted in the wrong place. It belongs on a stats group.

Comment: As it seems, `dataEllipse` _estimates_ the respective means and covariance matrix from the data set and then (by assuming an underlying multivariate normal distribution) draws the user-provided (see `levels` parameter) quantiles. These quantiles do not necessarily coincide with the quantiles of the empirical data, i.e. the data given in `eta1`.

Comment: cryo111, Thanks for your response. I was trying to find an equivalence in bivariate of what we have in the univariate setting when we calculate the 95% Normal Approximated Confidence Interval and hence coverage (# times the estimated interval covers the true value) from it.

Comment: The other comments explain pretty clearly why this is off-topic here.

Comment: Disagree that this is off-topic. See posted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why people are jumping on the OP. In context, it's clearly a programming question: it's about getting the empirical frequency of data points within a given ellipse, not a theoretical probability. The OP even posted code and a graph showing what they're trying to obtain.

It may be that they don't fully understand the statistical theory behind a 95% ellipse, but they didn't ask about that. Besides, making plots and calculating frequencies like this is an excellent way of coming to grips with the theory.

Anyway, here's some code that answers the narrowly-defined question of how to count the points within an ellipse obtained via a normal distribution (which is what underlies `dataEllipse`). The idea is to transform your data to the unit circle via principal components, then get the points within a certain radius of the origin.

```
within.ellipse <- function(x, y, plot.ellipse=TRUE)
{
    if(missing(y) && is.matrix(x) && ncol(x) == 2)
    {
        y <- x[,2]
        x <- x[,1]
    }

    if(plot.ellipse)
        dataEllipse(x, y, levels=0.95)

    d <- scale(prcomp(cbind(x, y), scale.=TRUE)$x)
    rad <- sqrt(2 * qf(.95, 2, nrow(d) - 1))
    mean(sqrt(d[,1]^2 + d[,2]^2) < rad)
}
```

It was also commented that a 95% data ellipse contains 95% of the data by definition. This is certainly not true, at least for normal-theory ellipses. If your distribution is particularly bad, the coverage frequency may not even converge to the assumed level as the sample size increases. Consider a generalised pareto distribution, for example:

```
library(evd) # for rgpd

# generalised pareto has no variance for shape > 0.5
z <- sapply(1:1000, function(...) within.ellipse(rgpd(100, shape=5), rgpd(100, shape=5), FALSE))
mean(z)
[[1] 0.97451

z <- sapply(1:1000, function(...) within.ellipse(rgpd(10000, shape=5), rgpd(10000, shape=5), FALSE))
mean(z)
[1] 0.9995808
```

Comment: +1! excellent even I think that `within.ellipse` need more explanation(how do you compute rad?)

Comment: Hong Ooi: Thanks for your reply, it is very helpful. So for my example  x<-eta[1,] y<-eta[2,]                                              
and apply your code, I am not sure how it will calculate the frequencies of points inside/outside the ellipse. Sorry for not understanding. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the `x` and `y` correspond to your `eta[,1]` and `eta[,2]`. If you run the code with a small sample (say 10 or 100 obervations), you should see that the fraction of points inside the ellipse corresponds to the printed output of the function.

Comment: Sorry, could you please help me with the code to print output of the function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. If you just run `within.ellipse(eta[,1], eta.[,2])` you should see it return a number. That number is the fraction of points inside the ellipse.